# Any tool to find declaration of IDs in Python code?

Tags: python

Can some tool or library find declaration of function/variable IDs in Python source code?
So i tell this tool or library (using it from my Windows app) ID name, source Python filename, and tool finds position of id declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [the `inspect` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html). Particularly, [`inspect.getsourcelines()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getsourcelines) and [`inspect.getsourcefile()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getsourcefile).